# Functionality in Microsoft Excel to automatically substitute abbreviations

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to get my mom used to Excel 2016, and we have the following problem:

In Excel 1998, there was a feature to automatically substitute small strings for text for full names, e.g.:

Entering "Tob" in a cell, and then selecting the next one (by pressing the enter key, or using the arrow keys), would trigger the cell to be autocompleted to "Tobacco".
There was a name register where you could manage such abbreviations, e.g.

```
"Tob" → "Tobacco"
"Imp" → "Import products"
"Abb" → "Abbreviations"
```

EDIT:
We found something, called "Name register", but it's not what we want. Basically it allows for aliases for cell ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "autocorrect" in Office currently.
You can't get it Excel only, it'll behave the same in all Office applications.

> You can use the AutoCorrect feature to do the following:
>
> - Automatically detect and correct typos and misspelled words – For example, if you type teh plus a space, AutoCorrect replaces what you
>     typed with the. Or if you type This is theh ouse plus a space,
>     AutoCorrect replaces what you typed with This is the house.
> - Quickly insert symbols – For example, type (c) to insert ©. If the list of built-in AutoCorrect entries doesn't contain the symbols that
>     you want, you can add entries.
> - **Quickly insert any long piece of text** – For example, if you need to repeatedly enter a phrase such as return on investment, you can set up
>     the program to automatically enter this phrase when you type roi.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-autocorrect-options-for-capitalization-spelling-and-symbols-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f